# extract strings from list

Tags: python, string, list

I have this segment of code to extract the shortest path in a graph from one node to another

```
g = json_graph.node_link_graph(json.load(open("MPLS-topo.json")))
paths = nx.shortest_path(g, "H1", weight="weight")
for dest in paths.keys():  # Nicely output all those paths
  if dest == "H2":
    print "Shortest Path from H1 to {} is:".format(dest)
    print "{}".format(paths[dest])
```

the output of it is

```
 Shortest Path from H1 to H2 is:
 ['H1', u'S1', u'S2', u'S3', u'S5', u'H2']
```

I want to remove u and convert the path to string like this

```
 H1-S1-S2-S3-S5-H2
```

I tried this

```
 path = [s.replace('u', '') for s in paths[dest]]
 print path
 y = "-".join(path)
```

but it gives me the same output.
How can I do this in python?

Comment: 'u' is not a string, its signaling that it is Unicode encoded. This could help you: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: don't worry about the `u`. It does not affect the string operations you can do, and it won't appear in a file if you decide to write the list to a file. Just use the list like you normally would any list of strings

Answer (score 0):

Please try encode option which will convert unicode into string format:

```
path = [s.encode('utf-8') for s in li]
print("-".join(path))
```

This should give you the desired output.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was helpful

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.